CUPS refuses to print with "Unauthorized"
Connected Brother driverless printer to Debian 12 machine.  Attempting to print results in "lp: Unauthorized".   CUPS can print a test page successfully.
Checked OpenSuse CUPS Problem, but CUPS appears to be running in group 'lp' and I am in both group 'lp' and 'lpadmin'.
Checked ServerFault: CUPS Unauthorized.  I did not change any setting, but the current setting is "AuthInfoRequired None".  The comments in the config file says not to change the file while CUPS is running.
Some similar pages on SuperUser did not have specific answers for the error "Unauthorized".  I did turn on debug logging, but nothing appears out of the ordinary in the log, most lines say "Success".
Any ideas?
PS:
I uninstalled CUPS and tried installing again.  No luck.  This system is an upgrade of Debian 11 to Debian 12.  Printing worked fine on Debian 11.
PPS:  Apparently, "AuthInfoRequired negotiate" is required.  This lets an older printer work as expected.  However, a modern, driverless printer still does not, since it is not possible to add that line to the printers.conf file.  When CUPS is stopped, the entry for driverless printer disappears.  It seems that line has to be present for the specific printer, just to make things difficult.
PPPS: Someone on a different forum suggested adding a directive in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf that might make the "AuthInfoRequired" directive stick for all printers. This question, Set default for ANY printer, also asks the same.  Anyone have an answer for that?

A solution has been found. The actual answer will be determined soon, but a cupsd.conf file from another system was used with success. Details to follow.
